# XML Query with a variable not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<ChangeSet DBSchemaVersion="2.0.0.88" DBSyncVersion="15" ScopeId="1">
  <C op="I" PK="44">
    <User UserId="44" Role="3" UserName="Dummy1" />
  </C>
  <C op="I" PK="45">
    <User UserId="45" Role="3" UserName="Dummy2" />
  </C>
  <C op="I" PK="46">
    <User UserId="46" Role="3" UserName="Dummy3" />
  </C>
</ChangeSet>'

-- this works fine
SELECT [SyncTable].Col.query('User')
         FROM @xml.nodes('/ChangeSet/C[@op=''I'']') as [SyncTable](Col)
         FOR XML AUTO

-- this does not work
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'User'
SELECT [SyncTable].Col.query('sql:variable(''@tableName'')')
         FROM @xml.nodes('/ChangeSet/C[@op=''I'']') as [SyncTable](Col)
         FOR XML AUTO
```

The first returns:

```
<SyncTable><User UserId="44" Role="3" UserName="Dummy1"/></SyncTable><SyncTable><User UserId="45" Role="3" UserName="Dummy2"/></SyncTable><SyncTable><User UserId="46" Role="3" UserName="Dummy3"/></SyncTable>
```

The second returns:

```
<SyncTable>User</SyncTable><SyncTable>User</SyncTable><SyncTable>User</SyncTable>
```

I'm trying to do this in a procedure where the table name is a parameter.  Is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve?
SQL Server 2008 R2

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL variable value passed to the xquery expression as *literal string*, and AFAICS there is no way to inject *literal string* as xquery/xpath step expression.

However, there is a way around this, namely, filtering element having name equals *specific string*. Here, *specific string* is the *literal string* from SQL variable, for example :

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'User'
SELECT [SyncTable].Col.query('*[local-name()=sql:variable("@tableName")]')
         FROM @xml.nodes('/ChangeSet/C[@op="I"]') as [SyncTable](Col)
         FOR XML AUTO
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/712)</kbd>**

This part `*[local-name()=sql:variable("@tableName")]` reads : select any child of current context element, having `local-name` equals value of `@tableName` variable.